# how to compile in c99 mode?

Tags: windows, gcc, command-line, c99

I'm in a windows platform, is there any way to compile a program in command line in c99 mode , *without* having to type `-std=c99` in every statement ? my current gcc version is 4.4.1 .

Comment: Which GCC environment have you installed? There might be a `c99` command like on POSIX platforms.

Comment: mingw32 .. if thats what your looking for.

Comment: The main question has to be rewritten. I've answered `-std=c99`, but I had to delete my answer because the OP wanted other thing: `How to compile in C99 mode without typing -std=c99 in every statement?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc does not provide a way to specify command-line arguments via, for example, environment variables. If you want the effect of `-std=c99`, then at some level you're going to have to invoke the `gcc` command with that argument.

If you're invoking `gcc` from a Unix-like command shell, such as the one used with Cygwin, there might already be a `c99` command. POSIX requires such a command (it would be a wrapper around the `gcc` command). I don't have a Cygwin installation at the moment, so I can't check it. If it's not there, you can define a shell function:

```
c99() {
    gcc -std=c99 "$@"
}
```

If you're invoking it from a Windows MS-DOS-style command prompt, you can create a batch file called `c99.cmd` containing:

```
gcc -std=c99 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

and put it somewhere in your `%PATH%`.

Note that the latter method only handles up to 9 command-line arguments, which will *usually* be enough. (I think there are ways to handle more.)

You can of course add more arguments, like `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` if you want to catch more errors at compile time.

Note that I've named the command `c99` rather than `gcc` so that it doesn't try to invoke itself recursively. If you really want to be able to invoke it as `gcc`, you can specify the full path to the `gcc` executable (you'll have to find out what that is on your system). But that will make it more difficult to invoke `gcc` *without* the extra arguments.

Comment: Thnaks a lot for the detailed answer. the `c99.cmd` method looks quite nice. a question here is can the batch file be undone ? like if i for some reason want to go back to gcc mode compilation ? (im new to batch file stuffs)

Comment: @SomjitNag: You can delete the batch file, or just not use it.